# How to read data from elasticssearch in realtime using python?

Tags: python, elasticsearch, apache-kafka, real-time, apache-kafka-connect

I've already create mini pipeline about temperature in specific room with kafka using source connector elasticsearch [kafka-connect-elasticsearch-source](https://github.com/DarioBalinzo/kafka-connect-elasticsearch-source)
This source connector create automatically one topic that i will call here **"es-temperature"**
After i call python api to read the topic and filter the topic by condition that I store in file json.
I have already managed to create the filter by reading the topic **"es-temperature"** and create another topic to store the value.

But the problem is that I have Billions of data and The connector fetches only new data.
If I need only temperature pipeline data in 2012 this is impossible.

Right now, I try to read data from elasticsearch with python, use dataframe pandas and apply some filter, but elasticsearch uses a lot of resources which means that my computer become slow and **I lose all notion of the word realtime ** the filter process take 10min.
What should I do?

Here is my way to collect all data in elasticsearch:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from elasticsearch_dsl import Search
import pandas as pd

#connect to elasticsearch
client = Elasticsearch("http://localhost:1750")
s = Search(using=client, index="temperature")

#get all data in the index and convert to dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame([hit.to_dict() for hit in s.scan()])
```

That's not a realtime reader

sample data in elasticsearch:

```
"hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "temperature",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "oNaj-YMB_rSMMdMo9NFx",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "domain" : "CVC",
          "room" : "RT A2-4",
          "quality" : "192",
          "value" : "59.2",
          "name" : "DC10.R01.A.CVC.RT_10A24.MEL.FILTRE.ENCRA.MES",
          "textattr10" : "@192.168.40.73",
          "ts" : "2022-09-23T07:51:00.000Z",
          "textattr07" : "",
          "@timestamp" : "2022-09-23T09:52:00.310Z",
          "textattr04" : "DC10",
          "description" : "Encrassement filtres batterie",
          "textattr05" : "A2",
          "chrono" : "133084002600000000",
          "threshold" : "",
          "nature" : "R01",
          "@version" : "1",
          "rowid" : "133084002600000000",
          "textattr08" : ""
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "temperature",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "otaj-YMB_rSMMdMo9NFx",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "domain" : "CVC",
          "room" : "RT A1-1",
          "quality" : "192",
          "value" : "87.0",
          "name" : "DC10.R01.A.CVC.RT_10A11.HUMIDIF.FCT.MES",
          "textattr10" : "@192.168.40.69",
          "ts" : "2022-09-22T16:37:00.000Z",
          "textattr07" : "",
          "@timestamp" : "2022-09-22T18:37:00.302Z",
          "textattr04" : "DC10",
          "description" : "Fonctionnement humidification",
          "textattr05" : "A1",
          "chrono" : "133083454200000000",
          "threshold" : "",
          "nature" : "R01",
          "@version" : "1",
          "rowid" : "133083454200000000",
          "textattr08" : ""
        }
      }]
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: H and welcome to stackoverflow :) Why do you have a `Search` object but no `query`? Wouldn't this load the entire `temperature` index into RAM? What data do you need? What data is in the index? Could you clarify this?

Comment: I use search to get all data in elasticsearch, this is what i saw to read the data
do you have another way?